# Java canvas flickering when repainted even with BufferStrategy

Tags: java, canvas, graphics2d

I'm (trying) making a tetris clone in Java extending to Canvas but it flickers constantly. I looked everywhere for a solution and the answer is always use a BufferStrategy. I (think) added it but it is still flickering, maybe I'm doing it wrong.
Keep in mind that this is my first attempt at a real "project" so the code will look a bit messy and nonsensical.

This is my Main class (i removed the code that i believe is irrelevant to make it shorter)

```
public class Main extends Canvas implements Runnable{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tetris");
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        //more frame config

        Main m = new Main();
        m.setBounds(0, 25, WIDTH, HEIGHT - 25);
        frame.add(m);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        m.start();
    }

    public void start() {
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        t.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        init();
        boolean running = true;
        while(running) {
            update();
            BufferStrategy buff = getBufferStrategy();
            if(buff == null) {
                createBufferStrategy(2);
                continue;
            }
            Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) buff.getDrawGraphics();
            render(g);
            g.dispose();
            buff.show();
        }
    }

    public void init() {
        //create board and controls..

        tetrominoes = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Square>>();

        //creates first tetrominoe
        tetrominoes.add(new ArrayList<Square>());

        paintPiece(figure, tetrominoes.get(0), color);

    }

    public void update() {
        boolean fallAllowed = true;

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastDrop > 1000) {
            //Drop piece 1 block every second

            for(Square square : tetrominoes.get(tetrominoes.size() - 1)) {
                //checks if fall is allowed and sets to true if it is
            }
            if(fallAllowed) {
                for (Square square : tetrominoes.get(tetrominoes.size() - 1)) {
                    square.setSquareY(square.getSquareY() + 25);
                }
            }else {
                //when no more falling allowed creates new tetrominoe
                tetrominoes.add(new ArrayList<Square>());
                paintPiece(figure, tetrominoes.get(tetrominoes.size() - 1), color);
            }


            repaint();
            lastDrop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        if(control.left) {
            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastPressProcessed > 200) {
                //moves coordinates to left

                repaint();
                lastPressProcessed = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        }
        //deleted code for control.right and control.down

    }

    public void paintPiece(boolean[][] figure, ArrayList<Square> tetrominoe, int color) {

        //figures starting coordinates for new tetrominoe and creates 4 square objects with those coordinates
    }

    public void render(Graphics2D g) {
        board.paintBoard(g);

        //goes through each Square of every tetrominoe and paints it
        for (ArrayList<Square> tetrominoe : tetrominoes) {
            for (Square square : tetrominoe) {
                square.paintImage(g);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And Square class

```
class Square {

    private int squareX;
    private int squareY;
    private int squareW = 25;
    private int squareH = 25;
    private int imagePos = 0;

    public Square(int squareX, int squareY, int imagePos) {
        this.squareX = squareX;
        this.squareY = squareY;
        this.imagePos = imagePos;
    }

    public void paintImage(Graphics2D g) {
        g.drawImage(Main.tetrisBlocks[imagePos], squareX, squareY, squareW, squareH, null);
    }

    //getters and setters
```

Game logic (if relevant):
On start a new tetrominoe is created, a tetrominoe is an ArrayList of Square objects that contain the X, Y, W, H values that will be used to draw the square image.
The tetrominoe is stored inside a tetrominoes ArrayList.
The piece class contains all 7 possible tetrominoes each in a boolean 2d array variable.
So once i have a tetrominoe created with a piece chosen i call the paintPiece method, this method figures out the coordinates in which to draw to tetrominoe and creates 4 Square objects with those coordinates, all added to the tetrominoe arraylist.

Now the update method every second goes through each Square of the last tetrominoe in the tetrominoes arraylist using a forloop and adds 25 to the Y coordinate of every square of that tetrominoe(so that the piece can fall down) and calls the repaint() method.

The repaint() method draws the board (a black rectangle) and then iterates through each Square object in every tetrominoe that the tetrominoes ArrayList of ArrayList of Squares contains, for each square the square.paintImage(g) is called.

Repeat every time the falling piece reaches the bottom...

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses